# MQTT + (protocolbuf / flatbuf) = DDS?

Tags: mqtt, data-distribution-service, opendds

I have been using MQTT for a while. Now that I thought can we switch to DDS for performance improvement and tried some examples with DDS.

I wanted to compare DDS with Mqtt,

```
MQTT (TCP) + (protocolbuf / flatbuf) = DDS (TCP)
```

Is my understanding correct?

P.S I'm literally ignoring all the other QOS/SHM benefits DDS is offering.

Comment: You want to compare the two sides, but you are "ignoring all the other QOS/SHM benefits DDS is offering". Please be more specific about which aspects you are interested in comparing then.

Comment: Also, limiting DDS to a TCP transport is ignoring many benefits that UDP can provide.  Is TCP a requirement?

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek On a very higher level  1) I used MQTT TCP + JSON then 2) MQTT TCP with flatbuffers for serialization to network and de-serialize. Now I heard from people that DDS offers performance. Just wanted to do a high-level understanding and comparison on the performance without changing the system / arch much.

Comment: @CTucker TCP is not a requirement. Actually I use it the same host. I could use sharedmemory configuration for this. But comparing a MQTT TCP with DDS shm would injustice. Thus I wanted to use the same protocol then compare. PS: Am not an expert today with DDS.

Comment: "Performance" can mean a lot of different things to different people. What aspects are you looking for? Latency? Jitter? Throughput? Memory usage? Any fault tolerance requirements? Also, in line with what @CTucker wrote, "dumbing down" DDS for your comparison so that it looks like MQTT is not of much value. I think you would be better of describing (in more detail) how your current solution does not meet your  needs and then see if DDS could solve that.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek Thanks for your diligence. I do not have a problem. I would wanted to try with this as there is a lot of buzz around DDS and it is very difficult for a guy from mqtt  background to jump in and start. May be you already had any how to's? Can you share if possible? PS: NO intention for the public to have a misunderstanding about DDS.

Comment: I think you should look into zenoh (https://zenoh.io), it has equivalent if not better performance than DDS, it is easier to use and it runs well on Internet-Scale deployment down to micro-controllers. Finally it is open source and entirely written in Rust for performance and security. #zenoh